# Ionic Mobile app Open In android app using Affiliate Link

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile

How I can open Ionic android app in android mobile based on a link.
fore examples

I share a link to the user as https://example.com/abc/test

when this link open in mobile browser then
specific mobile app should be open like mobile app id is: com.example then
in mobile automaticall the app should be open , on open the link

Please help me for this one, I stuck in this one

Thanks to all of you

Comment: you can use Deeplinks for this. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links

Answer (score 0):

See the following blog post which shows how to deeplink your application

https://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/

Comment: thanks for sharing information.
i solve by this link

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links

Answer (score 0):

You can use Branch for opening an App using a branch link

[Link](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/cordova-phonegap-ionic#troubleshoot-issues)

Comment: Thanks for sharing information. i solve by this link capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links